Authorization Header ["User-Agent"];
What are some alternative ways to detect client capabilities if the User-Agent header is unreliable?
Is there a library or middleware in ASP.NET Core that simplifies working with the User-Agent header?
How can I use the User-Agent header to implement device-specific logic in my ASP.NET Core application?

What you mean about unreliable? Normally, we could detect it by using the request header, if the request doesn't contain this part,  you need set at the client side to use other information to let the server know the client device.


How can I use the User-Agent header to implement device-specific logic in my ASP.NET Core application?

To this part of your question, you can have something like this to get client information
var clientInfor = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request?.Headers["User-Agent"];

The HttpContextAccessor is a class that provides access to the current HttpContext. In ASP.NET Core, the HttpContext represents information about the current HTTP request, including request and response information
